# Django Channels send message to another channel layer

Tags: django, redis, django-channels, consumer, asgi

let me simplify my question in one sentence: **in one consumer, how can I access to another consumer to send message?**

---

basically, I have two consumers in seprated apps:

1. note consumer in note app to manage system and crud notifications.
2. chat consumer in chat app to manage social messaging

```py
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
  "http": django_asgi_app,
  "websocket": AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        SessionMiddlewareStack(
            AuthMiddlewareStack(
                URLRouter(
                    [
                        path('ws/chat/<int:pk>/', ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
                        path('ws/note/<int:pk>/', NoteConsumer.as_asgi()),
                    ]
                )
            )
        )
    ),
})
```

I am implementing `online status` function. it works like this:

note ws connection establishes in every page, as long as you are on our site, you have a notification ws to receive notification. this correspond to the idea of `online`, therefore, we can save online record to `True` in db on note ws connection, and `False` when disconnect, to indicate online status.

```py
class NoteConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):
    @database_sync_to_async
    def noteOnline(self):
        user = User.objects.get(pk=int(self.scope['user'].pk))
        user.chatProfile.online = True
        user.save()
    
    @database_sync_to_async
    def noteOffline(self):
        user = User.objects.get(pk=int(self.scope['user'].pk))
        user.chatProfile.online = False
        user.save()

    async def connect(self):
        # ...
        await self.noteOnline()

    async def disconnect(self):
        # ...
        await self.noteOffline()
```

in chat friends view, user may want to know if the target he/she is talking to logged off or not, without ws implementation, the information will not be updated immediately, they need to refresh, I don't like that. therefore, I want to add a messaging method in chat consumer:

```py
class ChatConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):
    async def online_status(self, event):
        # print(f"{event['user']} online to {self.room_name}")
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'type': 'online', 
            'message': event['message'], 
            'user': event['user'], 
        }))
```

which enable us to send online status notification to chat socket, in `chat.consumers`

```py
class NoteConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):
    # ...

    # try to get layer from ChatConsumer, in my mind,
    # get_channel_layer takes first arg as unique 
    # identifier of the socket layer and will find 
    # corresponding one for me, but seems not working 
    @database_sync_to_async
    def noteOnline(self):
        user = User.objects.get(pk=int(self.scope['user'].pk))
        user.chatProfile.online = True
        user.save()
        for cp in user.chatProfile.getRecentContact():
            # print(f'{user} connect to {self.room_name}')
            # async_to_sync(get_channel_layer)().group_send(
            get_channel_layer().group_send(
                'chat_{}'.format(cp.pk), 
                {
                    'type': 'online_status', 
                    'message': 'online', 
                    'user': user.pk, 
                }
            )

    @database_sync_to_async
    def noteOffline(self):
        user = User.objects.get(pk=int(self.scope['user'].pk))
        user.chatProfile.online = False
        user.save()
        for cp in user.chatProfile.getRecentContact():
            get_channel_layer().group_send(
                'chat_{}'.format(cp.pk), 
                {
                    'type': 'online_status', 
                    'message': 'offline', 
                    'user': user.pk, 
                }
            )
```

thank you so much for reading this long, the code above needs a little more explanation:

chat socket architecture: let's say you are `user1`, and you have a friend `user2`, `user1` uses `ws1` to receive message, and connects to `user2` to send message.

`chat profile iteration` gets me the pks of `who I talks to recently`, and send message to their `receiving socket`

---

I doubt anything went wrong, but it seems that `online_status` is never called. I wonder why this happens and will be very grateful for your help.

Comment: btw, all the `hashed print` returns solid result that I want, but `online_status` method is never executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I walked around with `channel_layer_alias`, but it did not work, it seems that my previous mindset was wrong: `as long as you have room name, you can access to the layer anywhere with get_channel_layer`

it is weird you can use `get_channel_layer` outside consumer, but not in another consumer, the channel layer can only be accessed within the consumer, which after I modified the code to this, it worked:

```py
class ChatConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):
    @staticmethod
    def send_online(sender_pk, receiver_pk):
        channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
        async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
            'chat_{}'.format(receiver_pk), 
            {
                'type': 'online_status', 
                'message': 'online', 
                'user': sender_pk, 
            }
        )

    @staticmethod
    def send_offline(sender_pk, receiver_pk):
        channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
        async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
            'chat_{}'.format(receiver_pk), 
            {
                'type': 'online_status', 
                'message': 'offline', 
                'user': sender_pk, 
            }
        )
```

```py
class NoteConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):
    @database_sync_to_async
    def noteOnline(self):
        from chat.consumers import ChatConsumer

        user = User.objects.get(pk=int(self.scope['user'].pk))
        user.chatProfile.online = True
        user.save()
        for cp in user.chatProfile.getRecentContact():
            ChatConsumer.send_online(user.pk, cp.pk)
            

    @database_sync_to_async
    def noteOffline(self):
        from chat.consumers import ChatConsumer

        user = User.objects.get(pk=int(self.scope['user'].pk))
        user.chatProfile.online = False
        user.save()
        for cp in user.chatProfile.getRecentContact():
            ChatConsumer.send_offline(user.pk, cp.pk)
```

I will leave this post here just in case some one run into this occasion and need a hand, if you have a better option, I am very willing to accept it as answer.